# Best practices to store credentials in your Python script

Tags: python

My setup is: the code is in the private repository in Github which I run from AWS EC2. 
I have this doubt where should I store the API and database credentials. My feeling at the moment is that no credentials should be stored in the code, instead, I should use the AWS Secret Manager to access them but then, you also connect to AWS. What is your view on it?  A disclosure, I am starting with Python, so, please, be gentle.

Comment: Dont store any credentials in code. Store them in some secure storage (like Secret Manager or Hashicorp Vault). Inject them at runtime using whatever deployment procedure you like. For connecting to AWS, use IAM roles whereever possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never store your secrets in code. In your case I  would  recommend AWS Secret Manager (Or secret parameters in AWS System Manager Parameter Store) and store your secrets there.
I would recommend to create an IAM role for your EC2 which has a policy which allows the role to read the correct secrets from AWS Secret Manager. Connect the role with an instance profile and the instance profile with the EC2. This is done automatically in the AWS console but not when your using CloudFormation. An instance profile is kind of a wrapper around a role that allows the role to be attached to an instance.

In this flow your EC2 instance will be allowed to read the secrets from system manager by using the instance profile and role. Roles are the recommended way to make AWS resources interact with each other because it uses temporary credentials and restricts access.

With the above setup you should be able to read the secrets from within your code like explained [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/secrets-manager.html). You can use boto3 (AWS SDK for Python) to interact from within the EC2 to the secrets manager.